# Angular.js: how to call a service once for all the app controllers

Tags: angularjs

I don't know if this is even one of the Angular concepts or possible to do but i have a service that call the user information (name, id, age, ...):

```
.factory('me', function($resource, API_URL, $q) {
    return {
        getUser: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var url = API_URL + 'api/me';
            $resource(url)
                .get(function(user) {
                    deferred.resolve(user);
                }, function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
})
```

I use this service in many `controllers` to get the `user` data and use it to send with other `http` calls. for example in my `newItemCtrl`

```
.controller('newItemCtrl', function($scope, $http, API_URL, me) {
```

i called the `me` service as i did in many other controllers

and am wondering is there a way to call this service only once and use it in all the controllers instead of x times in each controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do something similar all the time with services by setting the value to the service once it's returned the first time. Now once the data is set in the service it will return the stored user data instead of making a request to your server.

```
service('myService', function($q, $http) {
  this.data;
  var self = this;

  this.getMyData = function() {
    if (angular.isDefined(self.data)) {
      // use $q to return a promise
      return $q.when(self.data)
    }
    return $http.get('myurl').then(function(resp) {
      self.data = resp;
    })
  }

}
```

In your controller you can call `myService.getMyData()`

Comment: This approach will work but in my opinion setting the return to a value and only making the call if the value is not there is a better approach. It comes down to separation of concerns. A service or factory's job is to do or get. You could say we even abuse the do portion but I digress. A value or constant's job is to hold data. Separating out those two separate tasks will pay dividends in the long run as the application gets larger and more complex.

Comment: I understand what user295... is saying, but I don't fully understand what you are suggesting tuck. You are suggesting the service set a value and check it instead of setting "data" within the service? +1 for user295... btw, that's how I would have done it, but I could be completely wrong.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 not following what you're saying. This service is only making one call and then storing the return value. We use this approach it in a large, complex app and it works well

Comment: The service's job is not to hold data, it's to get the data. That's why Angular includes values and constants. I'll write an answer so I can code format.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assume Value1 and Service1 have been correctly injected
if (Value1.data === null) {
     Your_Var = Service1.call;
} else {
    Your_Var = Value1.data;
}
```

For simplicity sake I would put that in a ternary expression when implementing.

For DRY compliance.

Going with DRY we need a SharedFactoryFuncion to handle $http requests

```
Your_Var = Service1.call;
//Inside Service1.call
return Value1.data === undefined ? SharedFactoryFuncion.get("url") : Value1.data;
```

There are numerous ways to handle the return of data from .get() so I won't go there as it's not pertinent.

Comment: so you need to inject two objects? that seems unnecessary and confusing. It's also not DRY to repeat the above logic in every controller. When storing the data in a service you just need to call `myService.getData()`. To each his own

Comment: No, but having the service get and store data violates the single responsibility principle. I'll update to reflect DRY compliance.