# Getting results twice when calling service with controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I am building a simple controller, which also includes a service. This service returns a json. Now, my problem is, when i call the request function via the controller and print out the results, I get all objects twice.

So this is my code right now:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
    .factory('RequestService', ['$http', function($http){

        function getData() {
            return $http.get('../../mockdata/data.json')
        }

        return {
            getData: getData
        };
    }]) 

    .controller('MainCtrl', ['RequestService', function(RequestService) {

        var data = [];

        RequestService.getData()
            .success(function(allData) {
                data = allData[0];
                console.log(allData)
            })

  }]);
```

json: http://pastebin.com/dTcNDQeA

I guess, the problem must be somewhere around the .success, but I can`t find out why specifically.

**My Solution**: Finally it worked fine for me when I wrapped a function around the the service call in the controller. Still figuring out, why.

Comment: interesting. I bet the controller was getting initialized twice. if you put `console.log('hi')` in the controller, does it called twice?

Comment: true! fixed it some time later :)

Answer (score 2):

Try not returning anything from your service.

```
  .service('RequestService', ['$http', function($http){
        this.getData = function() {
           return $http.get('../../mockdata/data.json')
        }

    }])

   // controller 

   RequestService.getData().success(function(data){
      $scope.data = data;
   })
```

To only call the service once you can see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363017/angular-js-how-to-call-a-service-once-for-all-the-app-controllers/31363032#31363032)

Comment: hey, if i delete this line, i get the following error: TypeError: RequestService.getData is not a function
    at new <anonymous>

Comment: @threxx sorry! updated the answer. Need to set the function on the service.

Comment: still get this error: this.getData is not a function

Comment: @threxx added sample controller call and also removed `()` from `this.getData`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
angular.module('clientApp')
.service('RequestService', ['$http', function($http){

    var getData = function (handler) {
        $http.get('../../mockdata/data.json').success(handler)
    }

    return {
        getData: getData
    };
}]) 

.controller('MainCtrl', ['RequestService', function(RequestService) {

    var data = [];

    RequestService.getData(function(allData) {
            data = allData[0];
            console.log(allData)
        });

 }]);
```

Comment: when i do this, i still get double results. that`s super strange

Comment: Are you sure your json file has everything only once?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your service as if it were a factory.

Try, either:

change the `.service` to a `.factory`

or:

do `this.getData = function () { ... }`

(as @user2954587 says)

Comment: tried it with the factory, still get double results

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should return single object. May be JSON you are getting from backend has problem

Comment: i wrote i myself and it only has four entries, so don`t think the problem is with the json