# how to prevent rest API call in controller every time the route/page is visited

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling some rest API(s) in my Angular app to get data from server and display it on page (ex: home page). But every time I visit the page, the API is hit, and data is fetched and displayed, because in my Controller, I am calling the rest service. Is there any 'best' way I can 'save' the data on first call and then, when user visits the same page, display the 'saved' data instead of hitting rest services again and again?

Also, there will be instances when I would want to hit the API instead of displaying saved data (ex: when user logs out and logs in again, or when data updates on server). What's the best way with Angular to implement such functionality?

[Here is a working Plunker for demo of my current app.](https://plnkr.co/edit/lk3e383ExRVuDykicMKs?p=preview)
(Please see home.js for service call example).

```
angular.module('home').controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, DrinkService) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.loading = true;
  vm.greeting = "Drink World!";

  DrinkService.getDrinks().then(function(response) {
    vm.drinks = response.data.results;
    console.log(vm.drinks);
    vm.loading = false;
  });

}).factory('DrinkService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Randmness/DeathByCaffeine-Enyo/master/data/canonDbList_dbService.json';
    var drinkService = {};

    drinkService.getDrinks = function() {
      return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return response;
      });
    };

    return drinkService;
  }
]);
```

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Comment: Hey! Really sorry for the late reply (was stuck in some other task). Though I didn't try the solution yet, but it is definitely very helpful! Will mark green as soon as I try. Your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: thanks, no problem! good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service using `$q`. An example service would be

```
service('myService', function($q, $http) {
  this.data;
  var self = this;

  this.getMyData = function() {
    if (angular.isDefined(self.data)) {
      // use $q to return a promise
      return $q.when(self.data)
    }
    return $http.get('myurl').then(function(resp) {
      self.data = resp;
    })
  }

}
```

The service will set the value from the API the first time it's called and set the value on the service so subsequent calls use the saved data.

In your controller you can call `myService.getMyData()`

you can see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363017/angular-js-how-to-call-a-service-once-for-all-the-app-controllers/31363032#31363032)

Comment: I am trying to call the service method 'getMyData' in controller. When I try to log the value of service, it is returning an object. But when I am trying to log service.data, then it is giving 'undefined'. Can you please help a little bit. Please see this plunkr (home.js): https://plnkr.co/edit/lk3e383ExRVuDykicMKs?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem by attaching 'then' after myService.getMyData:

  DrinkService.getMyData().then(function() {
    vm.drinks = DrinkService.data;
    vm.loading = false;
  }); But please let me know if I used the correct approach! :)

Answer (score 2):

@user2954587 answer will help you. I would also like to add that services are singleton i.e they are created once and hence are perfect to store data, share data among other controllers etc. Controllers on other hand are bound to a view. Each time a view is loaded controller bound to it is loaded too. You also need to remove data from the service some times(in your case when you logout), just set inject `myService` to the controller where you perform the logout operation and set `data` to `undefined` .